# Unable to Decrypt in Laravel 5 with angularjs-crypto.js

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am unable to decrypt the Crypto-js encrypt value in laravel 5.

Angular js code:

```
var user1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.form.user, $rootScope.base64Key, { iv: $rootScope.iv });
var pass1 = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.form.password, $rootScope.base64Key, { iv: $rootScope.iv });
```

Laravel 5 Code :

```
$user = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('usr'));
$password = Crypt::decrypt(Input::get('pass'));
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Hi Jose, Do you have any solution to the above query.

Comment: Dear All, I have resolved the above mention issue with the help of below link. [link] (https://codedump.io/share/pPrtKofUzlK/1/encrypt-with-cryptojs-and-decrypt-with-php), Thanks to all of you who had helped, Thanks to Jose for neatly formatting  my question. Pls mark this question as completed.